# URL to load resources from the classpath in Java

Tags: java, url, classloader

In Java, you can load all kinds of resources using the same API but with different URL protocols:

```
file:///tmp.txt
http://127.0.0.1:8080/a.properties
jar:http://www.foo.com/bar/baz.jar!/COM/foo/Quux.class
```

This nicely decouples the actual loading of the resource from the application that needs the resource, and since a URL is just a String, resource loading is also very easily configurable.

Is there a protocol to load resources using the current classloader?
This is similar to the Jar protocol, except that I do not need to know which jar file or class folder the resource is coming from.

I can do that using [`Class.getResourceAsStream("a.xml")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)), of course, but that would require me to use a different API, and hence changes to existing code. I want to be able to use this in all places where I can specify a URL for the resource already, by just updating a property file.

Answer (score 367, accepted):

### Intro and basic Implementation

First up, you're going to need at least a URLStreamHandler.  This will actually open the connection to a given URL.  Notice that this is simply called `Handler`; this allows you to specify `java -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.my.protocols` and it will automatically be picked up, using the "simple" package name as the supported protocol (in this case "classpath").

#### Usage

```
new URL("classpath:org/my/package/resource.extension").openConnection();
```

#### Code

```
package org.my.protocols.classpath;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLStreamHandler;

/** A {@link URLStreamHandler} that handles resources on the classpath. */
public class Handler extends URLStreamHandler {
    /** The classloader to find resources from. */
    private final ClassLoader classLoader;

    public Handler() {
        this.classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    }

    public Handler(ClassLoader classLoader) {
        this.classLoader = classLoader;
    }

    @Override
    protected URLConnection openConnection(URL u) throws IOException {
        final URL resourceUrl = classLoader.getResource(u.getPath());
        return resourceUrl.openConnection();
    }
}
```

#### Launch issues

If you're anything like me, you don't want to rely on a property being set in the launch to get you somewhere (in my case, I like to keep my options open like Java WebStart - which is why *I* need all this).

### Workarounds/Enhancements

#### Manual code Handler specification

If you control the code, you can do

```
new URL(null, "classpath:some/package/resource.extension", new org.my.protocols.classpath.Handler(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()))
```

and this will use your handler to open the connection.

But again, this is less than satisfactory, as you don't need a URL to do this - you want to do this because some lib you can't (or don't want to) control wants urls...

#### JVM Handler registration

The ultimate option is to register a `URLStreamHandlerFactory` that will handle all urls across the jvm:

```
package my.org.url;

import java.net.URLStreamHandler;
import java.net.URLStreamHandlerFactory;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

class ConfigurableStreamHandlerFactory implements URLStreamHandlerFactory {
    private final Map<String, URLStreamHandler> protocolHandlers;

    public ConfigurableStreamHandlerFactory(String protocol, URLStreamHandler urlHandler) {
        protocolHandlers = new HashMap<String, URLStreamHandler>();
        addHandler(protocol, urlHandler);
    }

    public void addHandler(String protocol, URLStreamHandler urlHandler) {
        protocolHandlers.put(protocol, urlHandler);
    }

    public URLStreamHandler createURLStreamHandler(String protocol) {
        return protocolHandlers.get(protocol);
    }
}
```

To register the handler, call `URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory()` with your configured factory.  Then do `new URL("classpath:org/my/package/resource.extension")` like the first example and away you go.

#### JVM Handler Registration Issue

Note that this method may only be called once per JVM, and note well that Tomcat will use this method to register a JNDI handler (AFAIK).  Try Jetty (I will be); at worst, you can use the method first and then it has to work around you!

### License

*I release this to the public domain, and ask that if you wish to modify that you start a OSS project somewhere and comment here with the details.  A better implementation would be to have a `URLStreamHandlerFactory` that uses `ThreadLocal`s to store `URLStreamHandler`s for each `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()`. I'll even give you my modifications and test classes.*

Comment: @Stephen this is exactly what I'm looking for. Can you please share your updates with me? I can include as part of my `com.github.fommil.common-utils` package that I plan to update and release soon via Sonatype.

Comment: Note that you can also use `System.setProperty()` to register the protocol. Like `System.setProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs", "org.my.protocols");`

Comment: Java 9+ has an easier method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56088592/511976

Answer (score 114):

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("someresource.xxx");
```

That should do it.

Comment: "I can do that using Class.getResourceAsStream("a.xml"), of course, but that would require me to use a different API, and hence changes to existing code. I want to be able to use this in all places where I can specify a URL for the resource already, by just updating a property file."

Comment: -1 As pointed out by Thilo, this is something the OP considered and rejected.

Comment: getResource and getResourceAsStream are different methods.  Agreed that getResourceAsStream doesn't fit with the API, but getResource returns a URL, which is exactly what OP asked for.

Comment: @romacafe: Yes, you're right. This is a good alternative solution.

Comment: getResource() does not read from classpath. It reads from the filesystem.

Comment: @Halil: when called from a jar, it resolves to jar:file:/path/of/awesome.jar!/someresource.xxx

Comment: OP asked for property file solution, but others also come here because of the title of the question. And they like this dynamic solution :)

Comment: This is not working with Spring-boot package. But `new URL("classpath:/file.xml")` working

Answer (score 17):

From Java 9+ and up, you can define a new `URLStreamHandlerProvider`. The `URL` class uses the service loader framework to load it at run time.

Create a provider:

```java
package org.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLStreamHandler;
import java.net.spi.URLStreamHandlerProvider;

public class ClasspathURLStreamHandlerProvider extends URLStreamHandlerProvider {

    @Override
    public URLStreamHandler createURLStreamHandler(String protocol) {
        if ("classpath".equals(protocol)) {
            return new URLStreamHandler() {
                @Override
                protected URLConnection openConnection(URL u) throws IOException {
                    return ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(u.getPath()).openConnection();
                }
            };
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Create a file called `java.net.spi.URLStreamHandlerProvider` in the `META-INF/services` directory with the contents:

```
org.example.ClasspathURLStreamHandlerProvider
```

Now the URL class will use the provider when it sees something like:

```
URL url = new URL("classpath:myfile.txt");
```

Answer (score 16):

I think this is worth its own answer - if you're using Spring, you already have this with

```
Resource firstResource =
    context.getResource("http://www.google.fi/");
Resource anotherResource =
    context.getResource("classpath:some/resource/path/myTemplate.txt");
```

Like explained in the [spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html) and pointed out in the comments by skaffman.

Comment: IMHO Spring [`ResourceLoader.getResource()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) is more appropriate for the task (`ApplicationContext.getResource()` delegates to it under the hood)

Answer (score 10):

You can also set the property programmatically during startup:

```
final String key = "java.protocol.handler.pkgs";
String newValue = "org.my.protocols";
if (System.getProperty(key) != null) {
    final String previousValue = System.getProperty(key);
    newValue += "|" + previousValue;
}
System.setProperty(key, newValue);
```

Using this class:

```
package org.my.protocols.classpath;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLStreamHandler;

public class Handler extends URLStreamHandler {

    @Override
    protected URLConnection openConnection(final URL u) throws IOException {
        final URL resourceUrl = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(u.getPath());
        return resourceUrl.openConnection();
    }
}
```

Thus you get the least intrusive way to do this. :) java.net.URL will always use the current value from the system properties.

Comment: The code which adds extra package for lookup to `java.protocol.handler.pkgs` system variable can only be used if the handler aimed to process not yet "known" protocol such as `gopher://`. If the intention is to override "popular" protocol, like `file://` or `http://`, it could be too late to do it, as `java.net.URL#handlers` map is already added a "standard" handler for that protocol. So the only way out is to pass this variable to JVM.

Answer (score 6):

(Similar to [Azder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java/861522#861522), but a slightly different tact.)

I don't believe there is a predefined protocol handler for content from the classpath. (The so-called `classpath:` protocol).

However, Java does allow you to add your own protocols. This is done through providing concrete implementations [`java.net.URLStreamHandler`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLStreamHandler.html) and [`java.net.URLConnection`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html).

This article describes how a custom stream handler can be implemented:
http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/protocolhandlers/.

Comment: Do you know of a list of what protocols ship with the JVM ?

Answer (score 5):

I've created a class which helps to reduce errors in setting up custom handlers and takes advantage of the system property so there are no issues with calling a method first or not being in the right container.  There's  also an exception class if you get things wrong:

```
CustomURLScheme.java:
/*
 * The CustomURLScheme class has a static method for adding cutom protocol
 * handlers without getting bogged down with other class loaders and having to
 * call setURLStreamHandlerFactory before the next guy...
 */
package com.cybernostics.lib.net.customurl;

import java.net.URLStreamHandler;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Allows you to add your own URL handler without running into problems
 * of race conditions with setURLStream handler.
 * 
 * To add your custom protocol eg myprot://blahblah:
 * 
 * 1) Create a new protocol package which ends in myprot eg com.myfirm.protocols.myprot
 * 2) Create a subclass of URLStreamHandler called Handler in this package
 * 3) Before you use the protocol, call CustomURLScheme.add(com.myfirm.protocols.myprot.Handler.class);
 * @author jasonw
 */
public class CustomURLScheme
{

    // this is the package name required to implelent a Handler class
    private static Pattern packagePattern = Pattern.compile( "(.+\\.protocols)\\.[^\\.]+" );

    /**
     * Call this method with your handlerclass
     * @param handlerClass
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static void add( Class<? extends URLStreamHandler> handlerClass ) throws Exception
    {
        if ( handlerClass.getSimpleName().equals( "Handler" ) )
        {
            String pkgName = handlerClass.getPackage().getName();
            Matcher m = packagePattern.matcher( pkgName );

            if ( m.matches() )
            {
                String protocolPackage = m.group( 1 );
                add( protocolPackage );
            }
            else
            {
                throw new CustomURLHandlerException( "Your Handler class package must end in 'protocols.yourprotocolname' eg com.somefirm.blah.protocols.yourprotocol" );
            }

        }
        else
        {
            throw new CustomURLHandlerException( "Your handler class must be called 'Handler'" );
        }
    }

    private static void add( String handlerPackage )
    {
        // this property controls where java looks for
        // stream handlers - always uses current value.
        final String key = "java.protocol.handler.pkgs";

        String newValue = handlerPackage;
        if ( System.getProperty( key ) != null )
        {
            final String previousValue = System.getProperty( key );
            newValue += "|" + previousValue;
        }
        System.setProperty( key, newValue );
    }
}


CustomURLHandlerException.java:
/*
 * Exception if you get things mixed up creating a custom url protocol
 */
package com.cybernostics.lib.net.customurl;

/**
 *
 * @author jasonw
 */
public class CustomURLHandlerException extends Exception
{

    public CustomURLHandlerException(String msg )
    {
        super( msg );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

Inspire by @Stephen https://stackoverflow.com/a/1769454/980442
and http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java/exp/ch09_06.htm

To use

```
new URL("classpath:org/my/package/resource.extension").openConnection()
```

just create this class into `sun.net.www.protocol.classpath` package and  run it into Oracle JVM implementation to work like a charm.

```
package sun.net.www.protocol.classpath;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.net.URLStreamHandler;

public class Handler extends URLStreamHandler {

    @Override
    protected URLConnection openConnection(URL u) throws IOException {
        return Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(u.getPath()).openConnection();
    }
}
```

In case you are using another JVM implementation set the `java.protocol.handler.pkgs=sun.net.www.protocol` system property.

FYI: 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String)

Answer (score 4):

Solution with registering URLStreamHandlers is most correct, of course, but sometimes the simplest solution is needed. So, I use the following method for that:

```
/**
 * Opens a local file or remote resource represented by given path.
 * Supports protocols:
 * <ul>
 * <li>"file": file:///path/to/file/in/filesystem</li>
 * <li>"http" or "https": http://host/path/to/resource - gzipped resources are supported also</li>
 * <li>"classpath": classpath:path/to/resource</li>
 * </ul>
 *
 * @param path An URI-formatted path that points to resource to be loaded
 * @return Appropriate implementation of {@link InputStream}
 * @throws IOException in any case is stream cannot be opened
 */
public static InputStream getInputStreamFromPath(String path) throws IOException {
    InputStream is;
    String protocol = path.replaceFirst("^(\\w+):.+$", "$1").toLowerCase();
    switch (protocol) {
        case "http":
        case "https":
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(path).openConnection();
            int code = connection.getResponseCode();
            if (code >= 400) throw new IOException("Server returned error code #" + code);
            is = connection.getInputStream();
            String contentEncoding = connection.getContentEncoding();
            if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.equalsIgnoreCase("gzip"))
                is = new GZIPInputStream(is);
            break;
        case "file":
            is = new URL(path).openStream();
            break;
        case "classpath":
            is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(path.replaceFirst("^\\w+:", ""));
            break;
        default:
            throw new IOException("Missed or unsupported protocol in path '" + path + "'");
    }
    return is;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I dont know if there is one already, but you can make it yourself easilly.

That different protocols example looks to me like a facade pattern. You have a common interface when there are different implementations for each case.

You could use the same principle, make a ResourceLoader class which takes the string from your properties file, and checks for a custom protocol of ours

```
myprotocol:a.xml
myprotocol:file:///tmp.txt
myprotocol:http://127.0.0.1:8080/a.properties
myprotocol:jar:http://www.foo.com/bar/baz.jar!/COM/foo/Quux.class
```

strips the myprotocol: from the start of the string and then makes a decision of which way to load the resource, and just gives you the resource.

Comment: This doesnt work if you want a third party lib uses URLs and you perhaps want to handle resolution of resources for a particular protocol.

Answer (score 2):

An extension to [Dilums's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java/861674#861674):

Without changing code, you likely need pursue custom implementations of URL related interfaces as Dilum recommends.  To simplify things for you, I can recommend looking at the source for [Spring Framework's Resources](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/resources.html).  While the code is not in the form of a stream handler, it has been designed to do exactly what you are looking to do and is under the ASL 2.0 license, making it friendly enough for re-use in your code with due credit.

Comment: That page you reference states that "there is no standardized URL implementation that may be used to access a resource that needs to be obtained from the classpath, or relative to a ServletContext", which answers my question, I guess.

Comment: @Homeless: hang in there, young man.  With a little more experience, you'll soon be posting comments in no time.

Answer (score 2):

In a Spring Boot app, I used the following to get the file URL,

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("PromotionalOfferIdServiceV2.wsdl")
```

Comment: This also works in plain Java (tested with Java14, on a Maven project with resources at `src/main/resources`).

Answer (score 2):

If you have tomcat on the classpath, it's as simple as:

```
TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.register();
```

This will register handlers for "war" and "classpath" protocols.

Answer (score 1):

I try to avoid the `URL` class and instead rely on `URI`. Thus for things that need `URL` where I would like to do Spring Resource like lookup with out Spring I do the following:

```
public static URL toURL(URI u, ClassLoader loader) throws MalformedURLException {
    if ("classpath".equals(u.getScheme())) {
        String path = u.getPath();
        if (path.startsWith("/")){
            path = path.substring("/".length());
        }
        return loader.getResource(path);
    }
    else if (u.getScheme() == null && u.getPath() != null) {
        //Assume that its a file.
        return new File(u.getPath()).toURI().toURL();
    }
    else {
        return u.toURL();
    }
}
```

To create a URI you can use `URI.create(..)`. This way is also better because you control the `ClassLoader` that will do the resource lookup.

I noticed some other answers trying to parse the URL as a String to detect the scheme. I think its better to pass around URI and use it to parse instead.

[*I have actually filed an issue a while ago with Spring Source begging them to separate out their Resource code from `core` so that you don't need all the other Spring stuff.*](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12508)