# Is it possible to resolve css as a classpath resource using Flying Saucer (XHTML-Renderer)?

Tags: java, css, xhtmlrenderer, flying-saucer

I'm trying to package up resources into a jar, but I'm having trouble getting Flying Saucer to find the css on the classpath - [I can't construct a URL easily to be able to resolve this seamlessly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java).

Does Flying saucer have a way of specifying resource packages on the classpath to resolve items and images?

Note: I'm running this in a webstart application that does not have file system writing permissions, so jar expansion is not really an option.

Comment: You'll have a better chance of getting an answer if you show a small example of how you're loading the file, and the file itself. Assuming that FS uses a URLConnection to load stylesheets, the answers in your referenced question should do the trick (although they don't actually show the code to add a URL scheme resolver).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should implement a UserAgentCallback that you feed to the XHTMLPanel, something like this:

```
private static class UAC extends NaiveUserAgent {
    @Override
    public String resolveURI(String uri) {
        return uri;
    }

    @Override
    protected InputStream resolveAndOpenStream(String uri) {
        java.io.InputStream is = null;
        URL url = UAC.class.getResource(uri);
        if (url == null) {
            XRLog.load("Didn't find resource [" + uri + "].");
            return null;
        }
        try {
            is = url.openStream();
        }
        catch (java.net.MalformedURLException e) {
            XRLog.exception("bad URL given: " + uri, e);
        }
        catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
            XRLog.exception("item at URI " + uri + " not found");
        }
        catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            XRLog.exception("IO problem for " + uri, e);
        }
        return is;
    }
}

XHTMLPanel panel = new XHTMLPanel(new UAC());
```

Answer (score 4):

My solution is

```
private static class UserAgentCallback extends ITextUserAgent {
    public UserAgentCallback(ITextOutputDevice outputDevice, SharedContext sharedContext) {
        super(outputDevice);
        setSharedContext(sharedContext);
    }

    @Override
    public String resolveURI(String uri) {
        return uri;
    }

    @Override
    protected InputStream resolveAndOpenStream(String uri) {
        java.io.InputStream is = null;
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new ClassPathResource("/META-INF/pdfTemplates/" + uri).getURL();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            XRLog.exception("bad URL given: " + uri, e);
        }
        if (url == null) {
            XRLog.load("Didn't find resource [" + uri + "].");
            return null;
        }
        try {
            is = url.openStream();
        } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException e) {
            XRLog.exception("bad URL given: " + uri, e);
        } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
            XRLog.exception("item at URI " + uri + " not found");
        } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
            XRLog.exception("IO problem for " + uri, e);
        }
        return is;
    }
}
```

and invocation:

```
renderer.getSharedContext()
                .setUserAgentCallback(new UserAgentCallback(renderer.getOutputDevice(), renderer.getSharedContext()));
```

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that flying saucer does not have a way of specifying resources on the classpath, so I work around by making a [classpath: protocol url handler at the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java/1769454#1769454)

#### Post Implementation Findings

It would seem that the some of the premises of this question are invalid.  After writing my own classpath URL loader, I found that you need to request `<all-permissions/>` in the jnlp to be able to use `URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory()`.  In fact, you need to request all permissions to do just about anything fancy (even though you're only modifying your own sand-box).  See [the full list here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/permissions.html).

In short, this means that I *am* able to extract files to the operating system.  But it's nice having a classpath loader now...