# FlyingSaucer: convert an HTML document to PDF ignoring external CSS?

Tags: html, css, pdf, groovy, flying-saucer

I'm using the following to convert HTML to PDF:

```
InputStream convert(InputStream fileInputStream) {

        PipedInputStream inputStream = new PipedInputStream()
        PipedOutputStream outputStream = new PipedOutputStream(inputStream)
        new Thread({
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = builder.parse(fileInputStream)

            ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer()
            renderer.setDocument(document, "")
             renderer.layout()
            renderer.createPDF(outputStream)
        }).start()

        return inputStream
    }
```

From the documentation, apparently I should be able to set a "User Agent" resolver somewhere, but I'm not sure where, exactly. Anyone know how to ignore external CSS in a document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the same question but my answer for that one will work here too: [Resolving protected resources with Flying Saucer (ITextRenderer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782876/resolving-protected-resources-with-flying-saucer-itextrenderer/5044672#5044672)

Override this method:

```
public CSSResource getCSSResource(String uri) {
    return new CSSResource(resolveAndOpenStream(uri));
}
```

with

```
public CSSResource getCSSResource(String uri) {
    return new CSSResource(new ByteArrayInputStream([] as byte[]));
}
```

Comment: How do I not resolve? I tried retuning null, but that gives a nullpointerexception.

java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.xhtmlrenderer.context.StylesheetFactoryImpl.parse(StylesheetFactoryImpl.java:93)

Comment: Yes, as you updated you have to return a CSSResource with an empty InputStream.