# Java - class.getResource returns null

Tags: java, url

I am using the following to get the URL of this particular file, but it returns null. Does anyone have any suggestions as to the problem or an alternate way to do this?

```
URL url = ExchangeInterceptor.class.getResource("GeoIP.dat");
```

Comment: you can see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65173942/4797289

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59156951/873282. Reason: I stepped though `getResource` using the debugger. There, the JDK searched `classes` only, not `resources` (where the file was located). In my case, it worked with gradle, but not with IntelliJ.

Answer (score 76):

For those who use **Intellij Idea**: check for **Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Resource patterns**.

The setting contains all extensions that should be interpreted as resources. If an extension does not comply to any pattern here, class.getResource will return null for resources using this extension.

Comment: This answer is not applicable to Maven projects

Comment: @Sam What would be the solution for maven projects?

Comment: This is because Intellij won't copy "non-resource" files to your target folder.  Hence that file is nowhere to be found and loaded.

Comment: In case anybody is having trouble finding it, these days the setting is located at **Settings ▶ Build, Execution, Deployment ▶ Compiler ▶ Resource patterns**

Comment: Another potential cause is if the project is a gradle project intellij syncs with the build file, so the resources need correctly specifying there in order to be compiled into the files that are run in a debugging session.

Comment: @maja For maven projects you have to add resource includes like so https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html - That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 48):

The path is relative to the classpath root and if you don't give an absolute path, it is looking in the same package as the class you're using (in this case `ExchangeInterceptor`). To find something in the root use `/GeoIP.dat`.

Comment: This is really the answer. Everything else is just a bit nonsensical. Except maybe for IntelliJ hint.

Answer (score 36):

Use the `getResource` method of the class' `ClassLoader`

```
URL url = ExchangeInterceptor.class.getClassLoader().getResource("GeoIP.dat");
```

Comment: Worked for me, but could anyone explain why it doesn't work with class.getRessource()?

Answer (score 19):

I solved this problem by pointing out the `resource root` on IDEA.

Initially the directory was so and the icon was a plain folder icon

**Before**

[image]

`Right click` on a directory (or just the project name) -> `Mark directory As` -> `Resource Root`.

**After**

[image: after]

Recompile & rejoice :P

Comment: This is the answer for who that use IDEA.

Answer (score 13):

I've faced with the similar problem. From **Java SE API** for [getResource​(String name)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) :

> If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.

So I've added `'/'` before my directory : `MyClass.class.getResource("/dir_name/")`.

In your case try to add `'/'` before your file name:

`URL url = ExchangeInterceptor.class.getResource("/GeoIP.dat");`

Answer (score 8):

Just in case someone still has problems to understand that:

.getResource() grants you access to the local bin folder. That means, your resources need to be located in YourProject/bin/package/. The root folder is YourProject/bin/ and can be accssed by adding the prefix / to the String argument, like iirekm said.

Comment: It does not point to a specific folder at all. It just points to the classpath. You should see it the other way round: the bin folder which you're talking about is part of the runtime classpath.

Comment: well, I've tried to use the same method too and got the same error as the original poster. I fixed it by adding the files to the paths I mentioned, so I thought I should share this "discovery"

Comment: You just discovered one of the paths of the classpath. OP has it already in the classpath, OP was just accessing it with the wrong path.

Answer (score 8):

If you're using Gradle and IntelliJ, **and** changing `Resource patterns` didn't work, **and** your resource roots are set correctly...you can try this:

[image]

`Settings > Build, Execution, Delpoyment > Build Tools > Gradle > Runner > Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle`. (IntelliJ 2017.3.3)

Source: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-176738#comment=27-2518612

Comment: BTW, looking back on this now...I don't necessarily know that I'd *recommend* this as a good solution, as the Gradle integration in this case seems rough. But if it works for you, great.

Answer (score 5):

No, that is the right way afaik. Make sure the resource is on your classpath. This is often the cause of these types of problems.

Answer (score 5):

While using IntelliJ, I generated the project as a JavaFX app and then added maven framework support to it. Turns out, I then placed my resource in `src/main/resources` and had to add `./` behind every resource name that while using them in the code.

Also as stated in a previous answer, only loading the resource by a classLoader worked.

So for me, the final URL loading was done using:

`URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(String.format(".%ssample.fxml", File.separatorChar));`

The `File.separatorChar` returns `/` on *nix and `\` on windows.

Answer (score 3):

This is my example solution. Work for me.

The project structure:

```
•   Source Packages
   •    game
       •    Game.java
   •    game.images
       •    tas_right.png
```

In the game class:

```
URL path=this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/tas_right.png")
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix it by adding "./" to the beginning of the file like this:

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("./file.txt")
```

Answer (score 2):

Where do you have put this GeoIP.dat? In the same package as ExchangeInterceptor, or in the "root" package. If in the same package, your code is OK, if in the root - add '/' prefix.

Maybe you're using M2Eclipse? If configured incorrectly, it also may result in such problems. Another cause of such problems may be: misconfigured classloaders, misconfigured OSGi, ...

Answer (score 2):

The file needs to be in the classpath, e.g.: -

bin/my/package/GeoIP.dat

The / prefix seems to be a lie. The following would work.

```
URL url = ExchangeInterceptor.class.getResource("my/package/GeoIP.dat");
```

I suspect the issue is that you do not have the file in the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of having the resource file in the same folder as your source files, create a `resources` folder parallel to the `java` source folder.

Before:

- src

  - main

    - java

      - MyClass.java
      - file.bin
      - file.txt

After:

- src

  - main

    - java

      - MyClass.java
    - resources

      - file.bin
      - file.txt

Answer (score 1):

say you have :

```
titleLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/uz/assets/icon.png")));//wrong !!
```

rightclick on the folder(mine is `assets`) an set `Mark Directory as Resources`
if you dont see that rightclick on project name and pickup `Open module settings`

[image]

Rightclick on resorces folder(`assets` in my case)
and select 'Resources'
Now go back to the above java instruction and remove path BUT leave `/`
like:

```
titleLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/icon.png")));// correct one
```

Answer (score 1):

**Facts**:

1. IntelliJ puts compiled classes to `out/production/classes`.
2. IntelliJ puts resources to `out/production/resources`.
3. IntelliJ puts `out/production/classes` as first in the class path
4. The JDK searches the **first** directory in the classpath only [[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59157134/873282)]

**Consequence**: Resources are not found, independently whether `MyClass.class` or `myClassInstance.getClass()` is used.

**My workaround**: Copy all files from `out/production/resources` to `out/production/classes`. Then, it works.

---

Links:

- The issue on YouTrack is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119280. Please vote it up.
- JetBrains support forum entry: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206261449-Adding-Resource-Files-to-Run-Configuration?page=1#community_comment_13498024913554

Answer (score 0):

I use Intellij version Ultimate 2019.3

**Go to**

> Settings -> Compiler -> Resource patterns.

Click ok.
Rerun Application/Server.

In my case, i included the jks in the project!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A warning to all using the `Path` or `Paths` classes in Java: if you are on the god forsaken operating system known as Windows you will not be able to use `Path.of` or `Paths.get` as this will put backslashes in your path which Java will attempt to load and promptly fail. Instead use this:

```java
Path.of(paths...).toString().replace(File.separator, "/")
```

You should always use this as it is OS independent. If anyone has a better or built in way please comment, I was unable to find one.

Answer (score 0):

Strangely effective in my case (IJ  2022.1.4) was: close project (for example, quit IDEA), delete the /.idea folder completely (egg, `rm -rd .idea`), open project. When it re-imports the project, it runs as expected. Note: you loose about everything not included in gradle configs.

Answer (score 0):

In intellij i had to Build > "Rebuild Project".
It seems it didn't automatically see the files i added to the maven resources directory.

Answer (score -1):

I realized using new File(location) works just fine in #dev and can also access files outside the /project folder

Comment: This is not an actual answer please refer to this guide on how to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score -3):

In case of **eclipse**.

Just a hint. Your code could be correct, but your jre configuration not. I ran into the the same error, nothing helped, until i checked the eclipse settings.

Make sure, that you set your execution environment right.

```
Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> use "jdk..." as compatible JRE
```

Comment: This doesn't really address the original question or explain why it would help with the OP issue.

Answer (score -5):

First, you need to make sure you are accessing the right file on the right path. You can verify that by getClass().getResource("GeoIP.dat").getAbsolutePath().

Secondly, the path specifier is case-sensitive, so make sure your file is not named "geoIP.dat" or "GeoIP.DAT".

Comment: You will get NullRef because `getResource` returns `null`, remember?