# NullPointerException when trying to use image resource

Tags: java, jar, nullpointerexception, project

I made a game in Java. It works completly fine in Eclipse.

I exported it as a Runnable JAR. When double-clicking on it's icon, it doesn't open. So I tried running the JAR from the command line.

I get a `NullPointerException` error, in a line of code that's trying to retrieve an image resource (as I said, it works fine inside Eclipse). This is the line of code where the error happens:

```
ball = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("sprites/ball.PNG"));
```

I have no idea what's wrong. Here is the structure of my project:

[image]

Any ideas? I'm starting to get desperate.

Thanks a lot for your help.

**EDIT**: I tried adding a `/` to the beginning of `sprites/ball.PNG` . Didn't help. Also tried to change `PNG` to `png`. Didn't work either.

Checked inside the JAR, the image is inside. I'm on Windows.

**Here is the stacktrace:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init><Unknown Source>
    at instPanel.<init><instPanel.java:17>
    at Main.<init><Main.java:23>
    at Main.main<Main.java:38>
```

**EDIT:** Could the fact that I'm using (default package) be a problem?

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853522/exporting-an-jar-file-in-eclipse-and-referencing-a-file

Comment: @theCoder: but why would he get a NPE?

Comment: put jar next to a file named sprites which has ball.PNG. If it works then image is not exported

Comment: Put the image into the folder next to the jar file that will solve your problem.

Comment: 1. Is the class referenced by this in the same Package as the image? 2. Have you checked the jar? Maybe there is no /sprites/ball.png .

Comment: @RAM I don't think they're in the same package. As you can see in my project structure I illustarated above, the `sprites` folder and the `(default package)` folder are both in the `src` folder. The sprites folder is not inside the `(default package)` folder. But is this a problem? I thought that using `(this.getClass().getResource("sprites/ball.PNG"));` uses the `src` folder as a starting point.

Comment: I meant jar not package in the first question. sorry

Comment: If you run `jar -tvf <name of jar>` is there a `sprites` folder and can you see `ball.png`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look inside the jar with an archive tool it should be like this.

```
JARROOT/*.class
JARROOT/sprites/ball.png
```

You can try following.

In Eclipse right click the sprites folder. Click `Build Path -> Use as Source Folder` and package the project again.

And your call to the resource should be 
`this.getClass().getResource("/sprites/ball.png");` or
`this.getClass().getResource("/ball.png");` 
depending on how Eclipse packaged the jar.

**EDIT:** Please read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).

If the string you pass to `getResource("")` begins with '/' it will be treated as an absolute path within the jar. If the string starts without '/' it will be treated as the relative path to the class.

Here is an image of a simple project with comments. 
The folder "icons" is a resource folder. Its content will be packaged inside the jar. In this case `JARROOT/other/zoom-out-icon.JPG` and `JARROOT/zoom-in-icon.jpg`.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean 'package the project again'?

Comment: I mean create the jar. Right click the Project -> Export -> Java -> JAR file.

Comment: Okay, tried it. Same error. This is getting really frustrating :\

Comment: What is the name of ball.png within the jar? Look it up. Is it "/sprites/ball.PNG", "ball.png", "ball.PNG"...?

Comment: It's `ball.png` , lower case png. It is located in the folder `sprites`, that is inside the JAR. This is exactly what I have in my code.
Could the problem be that I'm using the default package?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to call the `getResource` with /sprites/ball.PNG?

Other question: are you on linux system? If so, you should pay attention on uppercase (ball.PNG vs. ball.png).

**EDIT:**

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/sprites/ball.PNG"));
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
```

Comment: Please see my edit. I did try to add '/', and tried both lowercase png and uppercase PNG.

Comment: I will, but this means I'll have to change a lot of places in my code. And what I did, should work, I think. Also, in previous games I made, it worked. I'm curious as to why what I did doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You load the URL with `this.getClass().getResource("sprites/ball.PNG")` but it returns:
"A java.net.URL object or null if no resource with this name is found".

So the constructor from `ImageIcon(URL location)` gets null as value and if you look into the constructor you will see following line: `this(location, location.toExternalForm());`.

The problem lies in that exact line as location is null and therefor `location.toExternalForm()` throws your NPE.

You could fix it with

```
image = this.getClass().getResource("sprites/ball.PNG");
if (image != null) { 
    ball = new ImageIcon(image); 
}
```

but the underlying problem is that the image is not found.

What you can to to find (and fix) the error:

1 print somewhere the path in which it will be looking:

```
URL resource = this.getClass().getResource("/");
resource.getFile(); // print me somehwere

URL resource = this.getClass().getResource("img/");
resource.getFile(); // print me as well

URL resource = this.getClass().getResource("img/ball.PNG");
resource.getFile(); // print me as well
```

2 Ensure, that the image name / path matches the case exactly since it may be case sensitive.

Comment: Not sure I understand everything you wrote. But basically, you're saying that the program couldn't find the image resource. How can it be? The image resource is inside the sprites folder, which is inside the exported JAR. I checked.

Comment: try to move the image to your java package in a sub-package named sprites. i had the same problem once and just looked in my old code ;-) the problem is, that getResource starts looking in the actual packag of the class, if you want to have / as context there would be another way (which i don't remember atm)

Comment: Do you mean, create a new folder inside `(default package)`, name it `sprites`, and move all my image resources in there?
If so, I tried it. It doesn't work :\

Comment: i updated my answer for finding the error. this is what i did to fix it. i just played around with my code and i have my image in a /resources/ folder. if nothing helps, i can give you my code as as a working example (it is a simple java weather app example from a basic java swing training i held)

Comment: i can: http://www.file-upload.net/download-8547927/weather.zip.html
 there are 2 projects, weatherserver (downloads the actual weather) and 06SwingWeather (builds into an executable jar file and has the image loading in it, in AboutDialog.java). you have to build weatherserver first, then you can build the swingweather. if you got further questions just ask.

Comment: Code removed from file-upload again since the question is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the code you gave and ran into the same problem with the uppercase PNG file. Later, when using 'ball.png', and using the below command:

```
java -classpath test.jar MainClass
```

I am able to access the image. What is the command you are using?

Output of jar -tf Test.jar:

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
.classpath
Test.class
sprites/ball.png
.project
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. On a Windows 7 machine apparently running under the Netbeans IDE path names are *not* case sensitive - but running the JAR file under Java Se 8.2 on the same machine file names suddenly *are* case sensitive.