# Java Agent Use Image Resource

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I have got an Java Agent and I'm trying to use an ImageResource in the "JTreeCellRendererOpen" class from the "res" folder to show as image icon.

```
 ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/res/ntf.gif"));
    super.setIcon(icon);
```

I try the different examples in the following 
[NullPointerException when trying to use image resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328099/nullpointerexception-when-trying-to-use-image-resource) but I always get an NullPointerException.

Does somebody know how to access the given resource?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `getResourceAsStream()` instead of `getResource()`:

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
...
        InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ntf.gif");
        ImageIcon icon= new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(stream));
```

Put the resource files in Java Agent into folder "Res" with button "Import / Resource":

[image]

You'll see the files in Package Explorer like this then:

[image]

Comment: It's the same proble. I get a NullPointerException

Comment: With your new Answer my code runs without NullPointerException.. Thanks Knut!