# JavaFX warning: Argument 'getClass().getClassLoader().getResource( "view/RootLayout.fxml" )' might be null

Tags: intellij-idea, layout, javafx

IntelliJ Idea is giving me this warning:

```
Argument 'getClass().getClassLoader().getResource( "view/RootLayout.fxml" )' might be null
```

However, it always works.  I just want the clear warning, preferably without annotations or disabling the inspection.

Per this thread: [IntelliJ IDEA - getClass().getResource("...") return null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328040/intellij-idea-getclass-getresource-return-null)

- I have my resources folder set as a Resources Root.
- I added *.fxml to Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Compiler -> Resource patterns
- I even added ?*.fxml and !?*.fxml to cover more possibilities.

None of those seem to make any difference.

Here is my start() method:

```
@Override
public void start( Stage primaryStage ) throws Exception
{
    // Load the FXML file containing all of the UI elements.
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation( getClass().getResource( "view/RootLayout.fxml" ) );
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load( getClass().getClassLoader().getResource( "view/RootLayout.fxml" ) );

    // Create the stage and set the window title.
    primaryStage.setTitle( "SNMP Link Utilization" );

    // Set the scene using root, with the specified width and height.
    primaryStage.setScene( new Scene( root, 500, 600 ) );

    // Set the icon for a non-Maven build.
    //primaryStage.getIcons().add( new Image( "file:resources/images/nic.png" ) );
    // Set the icon for a Maven build.
    primaryStage.getIcons().add( new Image( "images/nic.png" ) );

    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong?  I've tried a few other ways of creating the Parent object, but all that I have tried end up failing.

Comment: That just looks like an over-zealous ide warning to me. I don't know IntelliJ very well but I suspect there's a way to configure that. You could put the result of the call to `getResource(...)` in a variable url and wrap the rest of your code in an `if (url != null) { ... }` (or just throw an exception if it is null), and maybe that would appease the warning, but that seems overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of that warning if you refactor the code a little bit this way:

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
            "view/RootLayout.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
```

Comment: This works, if I change the FXMLLoader line to this:

`FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader( Main.class.getResource( "../../../view/RootLayout.fxml" ) );`

Do you know why it "loses sight" of my Resources Root location?  I find this code kind of ugly.  Is there a way to get back to the shorter name, without the updirectory indicators?

Comment: So here is my code that works for me. https://pastebin.com/GcxG8U2u. So both `Test.class` and `Test.fxml` are in the test package and it finds the `.fxml` file without any exception.