# Read file from resources folder in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, json-schema-validator

I'm using Spring Boot and `json-schema-validator`. I'm trying to read a file called `jsonschema.json` from the `resources` folder. I've tried a few different ways but I can't get it to work. This is my code.

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("jsonschema.json").getFile());
JsonNode mySchema = JsonLoader.fromFile(file);
```

This is the location of the file.

[image]

And here I can see the file in the `classes` folder.

[image]

But when I run the code I get the following error.

```
jsonSchemaValidator error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user/Dev/Java/Java%20Programs/SystemRoutines/target/classes/jsonschema.json (No such file or directory)
```

What is it I'm doing wrong in my code?

Comment: Can you try this? `ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
  JsonNode mySchema = JsonLoader.getJson(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("jsonschema.json"));`

Comment: I like xubuntu too

Comment: first two lines of your question were the answer to my problem. you saved my long hours to go! ty @g3blv

ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("jsonschema.json").getFile());

Comment: why does this question has so many wrong answers?

Answer (score 184):

After spending a lot of time trying to resolve this issue, finally found a solution that works. The solution makes use of Spring's ResourceUtils.
Should work for json files as well.

Thanks for the well written page by Lokesh Gupta : [Blog](https://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/io/read-file-from-resources-folder/)

[image]

```java
package utils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.File;


public class Utils {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Utils.class.getName());

    public static Properties fetchProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:application.properties");
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            properties.load(in);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());
        }
        return properties;
    }
}
```

To answer a few concerns on the comments :

Pretty sure I had this running on Amazon EC2 using `java -jar target/image-service-slave-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Look at my github repo : https://github.com/johnsanthosh/image-service
to figure out the right way to run this from a JAR.

Comment: Thanks John for adding this. This works and certainly a better approach using the ResourceUtil.

Comment: This will work only if you try to run the application from IDE but when you run the jar it won't find the file for you.

Comment: Agree with Hassan, we should instead use `new ClassPathResource("filename").getInputStream()` if run the application from jar. [Detail](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access)

Comment: Agree with Hassan. As a caveat, ResourceUtils Javadoc is clear that the class is mainly for internal use. Check as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869428/classpath-resource-not-found-when-running-as-jar/25873705#25873705

Comment: @HassanMudassir Pretty sure I had this running on Amazon EC2 using java -jar target/image-service-slave-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Look at my github repo : https://github.com/johnsanthosh/image-service

Figure out the right way to package your JAR and this would work 100% ;)

Comment: Hassan is right! I think a fat jar or shadow jar will allow you to use the original method but @JingchaoLuan's method is best.

Comment: Spring ResourceUtils works for both JAR and IDE after removing the classpath: prefix. :)

Answer (score 83):

Very short answer: you are looking for the resource in the scope of a classloader's class instead of your target class. This should work:

```java
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("jsonschema.json").getFile());
JsonNode mySchema = JsonLoader.fromFile(file);
```

Also, that might be helpful reading:

- [What is the difference between Class.getResource() and ClassLoader.getResource()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource)
- [Strange behavior of Class.getResource() and ClassLoader.getResource() in executable jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269556/strange-behavior-of-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource-in-executa)
- [Loading resources using getClass().getResource()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343187/loading-resources-using-getclass-getresource)

P.S. there is a case when a project compiled on one machine and after that launched on another or inside Docker. In such a scenario path to your resource folder would be invalid and you would need to get it in runtime:

```java
ClassPathResource res = new ClassPathResource("jsonschema.json");    
File file = new File(res.getPath());
JsonNode mySchema = JsonLoader.fromFile(file);
```

***Update from 2020***

On top of that if you want to read resource file as a String, for example in your tests, you can use these static utils methods:

```java
public static String getResourceFileAsString(String fileName) {
    InputStream is = getResourceFileAsInputStream(fileName);
    if (is != null) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        return (String)reader.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException("resource not found");
    }
}

public static InputStream getResourceFileAsInputStream(String fileName) {
    ClassLoader classLoader = {CurrentClass}.class.getClassLoader();
    return classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
}
```

Example of usage:

```java
String soapXML = getResourceFileAsString("some_folder_in_resources/SOPA_request.xml");
```

Comment: `getClass().getResource("jsonschema.json")` returns `null`. I also tried `ClassPathResource res = new ClassPathResource("jsonschema.json")` which just returns `jsonschema.json`. Does this has something to do with that I'm using Spring Boot?

Comment: @g3blv regarding `getClass().getResource("jsonschema.json")` returns `null` I could refer to this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328040/intellij-idea-getclass-getresource-return-null/40065607. On top of that try to rebuild your project. Feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: @g3blv I provided update on the answer, please check

Comment: @povisenko I would suggest you to throw exception if `is` empty. It means that the file/resource you are looking for is not there.

Comment: complete answer. Works both in the IDE and for the jar. Thanks.

Comment: This returns null for me and the answer above only solves the issue.

Comment: It's generally a good practice to close a BufferedReader/InputStreamReader when you are done using it.

Answer (score 54):

if you have for example config folder under Resources folder 
I tried this Class working perfectly hope be useful

```
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:config/sample.txt")

//Read File Content
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
System.out.println(content);
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it works in IDE but when you make spring jar  input stream will help.

Answer (score 36):

Spent way too much time coming back to this page so just gonna leave this here:

```
File file = new ClassPathResource("data/data.json").getFile();
```

Comment: Works well in IDE but not in JAR-file.

Answer (score 34):

### 2021 The Best Way

---

Simplest way to read file is:

```java
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("jsonSchema.json");
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(resource.getFile());
```

Comment: This won't work in executable jar. Instead we can use `InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream();`

Answer (score 15):

See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56854431/4453282

```
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
```

Use these 2 imports.

Declare

```
@Autowired
ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
```

Use this in some function

```
Resource resource=resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:preferences.json");
```

In your case, as you need the file you may use following

`File file = resource.getFile()`

Reference:http://frugalisminds.com/spring/load-file-classpath-spring-boot/
As already mentioned in previous answers don't use ResourceUtils it doesn't work after deployment of JAR, this will work in IDE as well as after deployment

Comment: Which solution? I teseted it and its in PROD, not sure, you must be facing other issue.

Answer (score 15):

#### How to get resource reliably

To reliably get a file from the resources in Spring Boot application:

1. Find a way to pass abstract resource, for example, `InputStream`, `URL` instead of `File`
2. Use framework facilities to get the resource

### Example: read file from `resources`

```java
public class SpringBootResourcesApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClassPathResource resource = new ClassPathResource("/hello", SpringBootResourcesApplication.class);
        try (InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream()) {
            String string = new String(inputStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            System.out.println(string);
        }
    }
}
```

- [`ClassPathResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) is Spring's implementation of `Resource` - the abstract way to load *resource*. It is instantiated using the [`ClassPathResource(String, Class<?>)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html#ClassPathResource-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) constructor:

  - `/hello` is a path to the file

    - The leading slash loads file by absolute path in classpath

      - It is required because otherwise the path would be relative to the class
      - If you pass a `ClassLoader` instead of `Class`, the slash can be omitted
      - See also [What is the difference between Class.getResource() and ClassLoader.getResource()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608795/what-is-the-difference-between-class-getresource-and-classloader-getresource)
  - The second argument is the `Class` to load the resource by

    - Prefer passing the `Class` instead of `ClassLoader`, because [`ClassLoader.getResource` differs from `Class.getResource` in JPMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48768879/how-to-access-resource-using-class-loader-in-java-9)
- Project structure:

  ```
  ├── mvnw
  ├── mvnw.cmd
  ├── pom.xml
  └── src
      └── main
          ├── java
          │   └── com
          │       └── caco3
          │           └── springbootresources
          │               └── SpringBootResourcesApplication.java
          └── resources
              ├── application.properties
              └── hello
  ```

The example above works from both IDE and jar

##### Deeper explanation

###### Prefer abstract resources instead of `File`

- Examples of abstract resources are `InputStream` and `URL`
- Avoid using `File` because it is not always possible to get it from a classpath resource

  - E.g. the following code works in IDE:

  ```java
  public class SpringBootResourcesApplication {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
          ClassLoader classLoader = SpringBootResourcesApplication.class.getClassLoader();
          File file = new File(classLoader.getResource("hello").getFile());

          Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
                  .forEach(System.out::println);
      }
  }
  ```

  but fails with:

  ```
  java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: file:/home/caco3/IdeaProjects/spring-boot-resources/target/spring-boot-resources-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/hello
          at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:92)
          at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:111)
          at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:116)
  ```

  when Spring Boot jar run
- If you use external library, and it asks you for a resource, try to find a way to pass it an `InputStream` or `URL`

  - For example the `JsonLoader.fromFile` from the question could be replaced with [`JsonLoader.fromURL`](http://javadox.com/com.github.fge/jackson-coreutils/1.8/com/github/fge/jackson/JsonLoader.html#fromURL(java.net.URL)) method: it accepts `URL`

###### Use framework's facilities to get the resource:

Spring Framework enables access to classpath resources through [`ClassPathResource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html)

You can use it:

1. Directly, as in the example of reading file from `resources`
2. Indirectly:

   1. Using [`@Value`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Value.html):

      ```java
      @SpringBootApplication
      public class SpringBootResourcesApplication implements ApplicationRunner {
          @Value("classpath:/hello") // Do not use field injection
          private Resource resource;

          public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
              SpringApplication.run(SpringBootResourcesApplication.class, args);
          }

         @Override
         public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
             try (InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream()) {
                 String string = new String(inputStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                 System.out.println(string);
             }
         }
      }
      ```
   2. Using [`ResourceLoader`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html):

      ```java
      @SpringBootApplication
      public class SpringBootResourcesApplication implements ApplicationRunner {
          @Autowired // do not use field injection
          private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

          public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
              SpringApplication.run(SpringBootResourcesApplication.class, args);
          }

          @Override
          public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
              Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("/hello");
              try (InputStream inputStream = resource.getInputStream()) {
                  String string = new String(inputStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                  System.out.println(string);
              }
          }
      }
      ```

      - See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66986555/6486622) answer

Comment: ClassPathResource does not work in Fat jar

Comment: Can I ask you to provide more details, please, maybe, you can post a simple application where it does not work?

Answer (score 11):

Below is my working code.

```
List<sampleObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
File file = new ClassPathResource("json/test.json").getFile();
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
sampleObject = Arrays.asList(objectMapper.readValue(file, sampleObject[].class));
```

Hope it helps one!

Comment: json directory is under Resources of Spring project.

Answer (score 6):

stuck in the same issue, this helps me

```
URL resource = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("jsonschema.json");
JsonNode jsonNode = JsonLoader.fromURL(resource);
```

Comment: actually, this is almost the same as given answer
for more details see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14739550/difference-between-getclass-getclassloader-getresource-and-getclass-getres

Answer (score 6):

Here is my solution. May help someone;

It returns InputStream, but i assume you can read from it too.

```
InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("jsonschema.json");
```

Answer (score 5):

create json folder in resources as subfolder then add json file in folder then you can use this code : 
[image]

`import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;`

`InputStream is = TypeReference.class.getResourceAsStream("/json/fcmgoogletoken.json");`

this works in Docker.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest method to bring a resource from the classpath in the resources directory parsed into a String is the following one liner.

**As a String(Using Spring Libraries):**

```
         String resource = StreamUtils.copyToString(
                new ClassPathResource("resource.json").getInputStream(), defaultCharset());
```

This method uses the [StreamUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/StreamUtils.html) utility and streams the file as an input stream into a String in a concise compact way.

If you want the file as a byte array you can use basic Java File I/O libraries:

**As a byte array(Using Java Libraries):**

```
byte[] resource = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("/src/test/resources/resource.json"));
```

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [src/test/resources/html/registration.html] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Comment: It's right :         InputStream resource = new ClassPathResource(
                "html/test.html").getInputStream();

        String s = StreamUtils.copyToString(resource, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution with `ResourceUtils` and Java 11 `Files.readString` which takes care of UTF-8 encoding and resource closing

```
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
import static org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public  JsonNode getJsonData() throws IOException {
  ClassPathResource classPathResource = new 
  ClassPathResource("assets/data.json");
        byte[] byteArray = 
  copyToByteArray(classPathResource.getInputStream());
        return new ObjectMapper() //
                .readTree(new String(byteArray, UTF_8));
}
```

Or even simpler

Step 1 : Create your resource file lets say under /src/main/resources/data/test.data 
Step 2 : Define the value in `application.properties/yml`

```
com.test.package.data=#{new org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource("/data/test.data").getFile().getAbsolutePath()}
```

Step 3 : Get the file in your code

```
@Value("${com.test.package.data}")
private String dataFile;

private void readResourceFile() {
   Path path = Paths.get(dataFile);
   List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(path);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `spring` and `jackson` (most of the larger applications will), then use a simple oneliner:

`JsonNode json = new ObjectMapper().readTree(new ClassPathResource("filename").getFile());`

Answer (score 3):

Spring provides `ResourceLoader` which can be used to load files.

```
@Autowired
ResourceLoader resourceLoader;


// path could be anything under resources directory
File loadDirectory(String path){
        Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:"+path); 
        try {
            return resource.getFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.warn("Issue with loading path {} as file", path);
        }
        return null;
 }
```

Referred to this [link](https://smarterco.de/java-load-file-from-classpath-in-spring-boot/).

Answer (score 2):

just to add my solution as another 2 cents together with all other answers. I am using the Spring [DefaultResourceLoader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/DefaultResourceLoader.html) to get a [ResourceLoader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ResourceLoader.html). Then the Spring [FileCopyUtils](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/FileCopyUtils.html) to get the content of the resource file to a string.

```
import static java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;

import org.springframework.core.io.DefaultResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils;

public class ResourceReader {
    public static String readResourceFile(String path) {
        ResourceLoader resourceLoader = new DefaultResourceLoader();
        Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource(path);
        return asString(resource);
    }

    private static String asString(Resource resource) {
        try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream(), UTF_8)) {
            return FileCopyUtils.copyToString(reader);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Short and Simple:**

Works both in IDE and Jar.
If your file is under `resource` folder:

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/file.txt");
```

If your file is under `resource/folder` then simply change to:

```
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/folder/file.txt");
```

**Note:** Above snippet works in non-static methods

For static methods use the prefix `YourClass.class.getClass()`

Answer (score 1):

For me, the bug had two fixes.

1. Xml file which was named as SAMPLE.XML which was causing even the below solution to fail when deployed to aws ec2. The fix was to rename it to new_sample.xml and apply the solution given below.
2. Solution approach
   https://medium.com/@jonathan.henrique.smtp/reading-files-in-resource-path-from-jar-artifact-459ce00d2130

I was using Spring boot as jar and deployed to aws ec2
Java variant of the solution is as below :

```
package com.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;


public class XmlReader {

    private static Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XmlReader.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) {


      String fileLocation = "classpath:cbs_response.xml";
      String reponseXML = null;
      try (ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext()){

        Resource resource = appContext.getResource(fileLocation);
        if (resource.isReadable()) {
          BufferedReader reader =
              new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream()));
          Stream<String> lines = reader.lines();
          reponseXML = lines.collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

        }      
      } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using maven resource filter in your proyect, you need to configure what kind of file is going to be loaded in pom.xml. If you don't, no matter what class you choose to load the resource, it won't be found.

pom.xml

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.properties</include>
            <include>**/*.yml</include>
            <include>**/*.yaml</include>
            <include>**/*.json</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below works in both IDE and running it as a jar in the terminal,

```
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

@Value("classpath:jsonschema.json")
Resource schemaFile;
    
JsonSchemaFactory factory = JsonSchemaFactory.getInstance(SpecVersion.VersionFlag.V4);
JsonSchema jsonSchema = factory.getSchema(schemaFile.getInputStream());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to sanitize the path and replace %20 with a space, or rename your directory. Then it should work.

```
FileNotFoundException: /home/user/Dev/Java/Java%20Programs/SystemRoutines/target/classes/jsonschema.json
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem lies within the space in the folder-name where your project is placed.
/home/user/Dev/Java/Java%20Programs/SystemRoutines/target/classes/jsonschema.json

there is space between Java Programs.Renaming the folder name should make it work

Answer (score 0):

Using Spring **ResourceUtils.getFile()** you don't have to take care absolute path :)

```
 private String readDictionaryAsJson(String filename) throws IOException {
    String fileContent;
    try {
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:" + filename);
        Path path = file.toPath();
        Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path);
        fileContent = lines.collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
    return new fileContent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In application.properties

```
app.jsonSchema=classpath:jsonschema.json
```

On your Properties pojo:

**NOTE**: You can use any prefered way of reading configs from application.properties.

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app") 
public class ConfigProperties {
private Resource jsonSchema;

// standard getters and setters
}
```

In your class, read the resource from the Properties Pojo:

```
//Read the Resource and get the Input Stream
try (InputStream inStream = configProperties.getJsonSchema().getInputStream()) {
   //From here you can manipulate the Input Stream as desired....
   //Map the Input Stream to a Map
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map <String, Object> jsonMap = mapper.readValue(inStream, Map.class);
    //Convert the Map to a JSON obj
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonMap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, in 2023, Java users should be able to read a classpath file more easily.
With a simple instruction such as `new File("classpath:path-to-file")`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it using [PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html),

```
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();

Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath:*.json");

for (Resource resource: resources) {
    JsonNode mySchema = JsonLoader.fromFile(resource.getFile());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue and because I just had to get file path to send to file input stream, I did this way.

```
    String pfxCertificate ="src/main/resources/cert/filename.pfx";
    String pfxPassword = "1234";
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(pfxCertificate));
```

Answer (score -1):

```java
 private void managerWriteFileToClasspath() throws IOException {
        //get absolute path
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:application.yml");
        //get path to directory when is application.yml
        String parent = file.getParent();

        String separator = File.separator; //separator for various OS

        //create directory into src/main/resources.
        // You will see in target/classes
        String directoryPath = parent + separator + "data";
        Path newFilePath = Paths.get(directoryPath);
        Files.createDirectory(newFilePath);

        //create file into directory src/main/resources/data
        String fileTxt = parent + separator + "data" + separator + "example.txt";
        String str = "Hello hello";
        try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(fileTxt))){
            writer.write(str);
        }

        //read file in classpath (src/main/resources/data)
        String fileInClasspath = readFileInClasspath("data/example.txt");
        System.out.println(fileInClasspath);
    }


    private String readFileInClasspath(String filename) throws IOException {
        String fileContent ;
        try {
            File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:" + filename);
            Path path = file.toPath();
            Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path);
            fileContent = lines.collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw ex;
        }

        return  fileContent;
    }
```