# Can't get to a file located under src/main/resources/

Tags: java, getresource

I am trying to get to a file located under resources and get `null`:

```
 File propertiesFile = new File(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(file).getFile());

file = Log.csv
```

Even if the file is directly under resource or under one of the folders under it.
`this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(file)` - return `null`

Comment: where you have kept your file ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399422/read-file-from-resources-folder-in-spring-boot

Comment: make sure your file is present in src folder with correct name and format

Comment: If my file located directly under resources folder this code working: File propertiesFile = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(file).getFile()); if my file located under folder inside resources, it will not work. why?

Answer (score 1):

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(file).getFile()
```

capture the path till `resources` folder, if you have folder inside `resources` then you have to give that along with the file name.

for example -

```
resources -> folder -> test.csv
```

Then give file name :

```
String file = "folder/test.csv";
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Resources are not real `File`s on the file system, but on the *class path*. They could be packed in a jar with an URL like `"jar:file://.../xyz.jar!test.csv"`. Hence use an InputStream.

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/test.csv");
String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
Path path = Paths.get(userHome, "test2.csv");
Files.copy(in, path, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

Resources should be considered **read-only**; hence use them as template, initial empty file, read-only data or such.

The ClassLoader has only absolute paths under the root src/main/resources, without starting `/`. The Class has URLs relative to the class' package directory (but under src/main/resources), or starting with `/` an absolute path.