# Can not read spring boot packaging jar file

Tags: java, spring-boot, ubuntu

Environment: Ubuntu 18 + Spring boot 2.0 + JDK 11

It performs correctly when the application runs in IntelliJ, but it doesn't when reading the file after Spring boot maven plugin packaging file.

PS: The file indeed could be found in the packaged jar file!

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [jmxremote.password] 
cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the 
file system: jar:file:/home/XXX/YYY/target/YYY-1.0-Final.jar!/BOOT-
INF/classes!/jmxremote.password
```

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely attempting to use `java.io` classes to load a class path resource. This won't work, the `java.io` classes are designed only for file system operations.

Either extract `jmxremote.password` outside of the JAR or use the regular `InputStream` to access it as a class path resource e.g. by using [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-):

```
try (InputStream in : getClass().getResourceAsStream("/jmxremote.password")) {
  // read input
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

In the Spring Framework environment focus on using Spring utility tooling for handling resources (like the [`ResourceUtils` class](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ResourceUtils.html)) which nicely encapsulate lower-level, operating system dependent IO operations. The `ResourceUtils` already contains multiple traps to figure out if the project you are running is *exploded* (run in IDE) or *packaged* (inside a JAR file).

---

The answer provided by Karol seems the easiest and is relatively bullet-proof, until you need a certain level of flexibility to specify file location (inside a jar file but with the possibility to define it externally and provide somewhere in the file system). Then the approach with `getResourceAsStream()` method won't work.

Standard Java IO (`java.nio`) is using `FileSystemProvider` classes to delegate IO operations (like creating, reading and deleting files).

> A provider is identified by a URI *scheme*. The default provider is identified by the URI scheme "file." It creates the FileSystem that provides access to the file systems accessible to the Java virtual machine. The FileSystems class defines how file system providers are located and loaded.

So, if your file is somewhere on the filesystem, there are no issues, and everything works fine. Technically, the URL returned by `Application.class.getResource("").toURI()` starts with *file://* and contains a valid filesystem path.

Having said that, when your file "land" inside a jar file, the `Application.class.getResource("").toURI()` returns something more like *file://{jar-location}!/* (mind the exclamation mark), which is not a valid file schema path and Java doesn't know how to handle it. An additional file system provider needs registering.

```
FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, emptyMap());
```

Java figures out (based on URI) the scheme and registers a new file system. From now on, standard `java.nio` file operations can be used.

For example, if you have some files in a */webapp* folder which can (but don't need to) be inside a jar file and you'd like to list them.

```
// Load zip specific filesystem provider when run from inside a fat-jar
URI uri = Application.class.getResource("").toURI();
if (uri.toString().contains("!")) {
    FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, emptyMap());
}

URI rootFolder = Application.class.getResource("/webapp").toURI();
List<Path> banners = Files.list(Paths.get(rootFolder))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

Random rand = new Random();
Path path = banners.get(rand.nextInt(banners.size()));

log.info("Random image: {}", path.getFileName());
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

Installation of a new file system provider is global and should be done only once.

Comment: A standalone spring boot application fails with java.nio.file.NotDirectoryException as it finds ZipDirectoryStream. My opinion is not to stress File/FileSystem based access for jar bundled resources, rather use ResourceLoader or ClasspathResource to access the input stream of the resource. Most of the time the full-featured random access file falls under YAGNI.