# Path to file work only in IDE, but doesn't work from jar file

Tags: java, json, url, jar, readfile

I wanted load .json file with relative path (resources/jsonFiles/json.json). Everything work when I started app from IDE, but when I generate .jar file and run it I had error from nullPointer to file source. 
I checked this jar file and there path was jsonFiles/json.json (on app work /jsonFiles/json.json).
So I changed path and generated new .jar file, but this "mvn package" doesn't work, because junit tests don't work - can't find file in app.
I couldn't resolve this problem, thanks for help.

Work on app, but don't work in jar:

```
URL urlToJson = getClass().getResource("/jsonFiles/json.json");
       exampleList = objectMapper.readValue(new File(urlToJson.getPath())
               , exampleList.class);
```

Comment: and why can't you change the path in your tests?

Comment: Good idea, so maybe just path is bad, because I change path in tests (/jsonFiles/json.json), .jar generate well, but when I trying run .jar file is again:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at example.JsonMapper.<init>(JsonMapper.java:17)
        at example.Main.main(HomeworkApplication.java:12)

So is bad path? I don't know why

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20389418/1879409

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54225276/1184571 - this is my solution and perfectly solved. getClass() didn't work for my case.