# unable to access file in resources/static folder spring-boot

Tags: file, spring-boot, kotlin, readfile

I have a file in a location:
`/resources/static/fcm-admin`

It's absolute path: `/home/jitu/project-name/src/main/resources/static/fcm-admin`

I have tried to access this file in the following ways

```
val file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:fcm-admin")
```

It gives me an error
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [fcm-admin] cannot be resolved to an absolute file path because it does not exist`

I have tried to access the file in various ways but it is not working. **I just want to the access file `fcm-admin` without giving the full absolute path.** Anything will be helpful

**EDIT:**

So I'm able to access the file on local with the below code -

```
val file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:static/fcm-admin")
```

**But I'm not able to access it on the production server. And I'm getting below exception**

```
class path resource [static/fcm-admin] cannot be resolved to an absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/var/app/current/application.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/static/apple-app-site-association
```

Comment: Please refer to 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399422/read-file-from-resources-folder-in-spring-boot/44399541

Answer (score 2):

> You forgot to add static in the path
>
> ```
> val file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:static/fcm-admin")
> ```

**EDIT because of comment**

Load your file from Classpath:

```
val file = this.javaClass.classLoader.getResource("/static/fcm-admin").file;
```

When you load a resource using the class loader it will be start in the root of your classpath.

Comment: Indeed: `src/main/resources` is the "root" of the classpath, so you need the `static/fcm-admin` as path.

Comment: It is working on local but it not working on the server... I'm getting the following error `class path resource [static/fcm-admin] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: jar:file:/var/app/current/application.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/static/fcm-admin`

Comment: Check your jar file on the server. Does the file exist in your jar file?

Comment: @the-hand-of-NOD, I don't have access to that...Is there any other way?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, not working... It is generating exception `java.lang.IllegalStateException: this.javaClass.classLoad…urce("/static/fcm-admin") must not be null`

Comment: Are you sure that the file is in the JAR file?

Comment: @SimmonMartinelli, I'm not sure, But it is making jar file from the same local code. So it should be there in the jar file.

Comment: Open the JAR file and have a look if you are not sure

Comment: In the jar file, it's path is becoming `/BOOT-INF/classes/static/fcm-admin`

Comment: I cannot help directly with the problem but the 2 links might provide information about how to solve your problem: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/executable-jar.html#executable-jar-jar-file-structure and https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-build.html#howto-create-an-additional-executable-jar

Comment: @thehandofNOD, Yeah I understood but the problem is that I'm not able to access the jar file static path..... It is the above comment location. So my question is, how can I access that file in the static folder?

Comment: I don't know much about your project setup but you could try: `this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/static/fcm-admin")` if that does not work you could try to load your resource with the `@Value` spring-boot annotation: `@Value("classpath:/static/fcm-admin")` assuming that fcm-admin is your concrete file you want to load and not just a directory

Answer (score 1):

Local server can work with ClassPathResource but will fail on production

To solve error on production, change your code to

```
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamSource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ByteArrayResource;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

InputStream logoFileStrem = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:static/images/image.png").getInputStream();

InputStreamSource byteArrayResource = new ByteArrayResource(org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(logoFileStrem));
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent so many time, lot of code work on dev but not on prod.

I used SpringBoot with war in production.

To load a file in resources/static the only solution who work in dev and in prod :

```
val inputStream = Thread.currentThread().contextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("static/pathToTourFile/nameofFile.extension")
val texte :String =  inputStream.bufferedReader().use(BufferedReader::readText)
```