# How to get a java/resources file to InputStream?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an excel file in src/main/resources (/resources/files/templates). I want to read it to InputStream. I am not finding the right syntax for this.

```
String fn = "/resources/files/censusTemplates/SimpleStandardTemplate.xlsm";

    try {
        InputStream inputStream = new URL("file:///"  + fn).openStream();
```

Above is not  working. I think the path is wrong. How to give correct path for files stored in resources?

Comment: What have you tried? Could you show us some code of your attempts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read file from resources folder in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399422/read-file-from-resources-folder-in-spring-boot)

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me.

```java
InputStream is = YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("relative path to your file starting from resources folder");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in any method (static or non-static):

```java
String fn = "/resources/files/censusTemplates/SimpleStandardTemplate.xlsm";
InputStream in = Clazz.class.getResourceAsStream(fn);
```

Where `Clazz` is the name of the class you are in.

If you are in a non-static method:

```java
String fn = "/resources/files/censusTemplates/SimpleStandardTemplate.xlsm";
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(fn);
```