# How can I open file in Java Spring project With Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, file, tomcat, filenotfoundexception

I have a Java Spring project with a file in some package (In project).
But when I want to open it,

Tomcat handle it and searching this file in C:\Tools\apache-tomcat-9.0.35\bin

I am getting below exception while getting file by `new File("./src\\main\\resources\\directory\\myFile.txt");`

Exception

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Tools\apache-tomcat-9.0.35\bin\src\main\resources\directory\myFile.txt
```

Comment: Please, try to format your code blocks properly. Follow this link for further explanation: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the relative file location you are using "./src\main\resources\directory\myFile.txt".

When your code is running on tomcat your current directory is "C:\Tools\apache-tomcat-9.0.35\bin" and thats why the absolute path is "C:\Tools\apache-tomcat-9.0.35\bin\src\main\resources\directory\myFile.txt"

Possible solutions:

1. Include the file as a resource and use a classpath loader to load it.  See example below.
2. Use an absolute path to your file. (not a good solution)

Example from this link [Read file from resources folder in Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399422/read-file-from-resources-folder-in-spring-boot)

```
File file = new File(getClass().getResource("directory/myFile.txt").getFile());
```