# SpringBoot - how to read root and children folders from resources

Tags: java, spring-boot

How can I read some folders from resources? Currently I have the following structure:

```
src/
- resources/
--/postman/
---foldera/
----file1.json
----file2.json
---folderb/
----file1.json
----file2.json
```

Is there any way to read those files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399422/read-file-from-resources-folder-in-spring-boot .Does this help ?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-classpath-file-access