# What's the right way to load a file in application context in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, applicationcontext

I have an XML file (notice.xml) that I want to load into my Spring Boot Application. This file will be served to an API after some modification. I want this file to be loaded into the memory to minimize the I/O. What's the right way to load this file into memory at boot time, or just after start up?

Comment: What kind of data? Master Data or Reference Data? If you are not sure, please describe what informations are stored in the notice.xml!?

Comment: It contains a few statements that I need to show as part of the API responses. Not too sure of the terminologies here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is, buy loading the Resource with `@Value("classpath:FILENAME)`

but there are tons of ways, you can try. To get a better understanding you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68913967/14726136)