# Path of resources folder in controller in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am tiring to access file from resource folder in my controller class but not able to traverse path is there any way witch I can access that fie easily or how can I traverse to paths.

**The file with i want to use in my controller**

[image: The file with i want to use my controller]

**Code in controller class**

```
String nodeFilePath = "D:/CodeFactory/TestCases/JavaScript/YamlToJson.js";      
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("node", nodeFilePath);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
```

nodeFilePath  what i want to replace with the file path in resources

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399422/read-file-from-resources-folder-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use  **ResourceLoader**

then use it like this

```
 @Autowired
 private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;

 Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:YamlToJson.js");
```

here detail of what Resource can extract for you https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html