# Where to put google-services.json file (that has API keys) in a Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, firebase, jax-rs

I am trying to understand the `resources` directory in a Spring Boot application and if it is the correct place to place my `google-services.json` file.

Are the files put in the `resources` folder visible in any way to the public when the application is launched? (e.g. can a random user on the internet list what is in the `resources` directory)? Or is that folder private only to the application?

I want to make sure no random user on the internet can get access to the `google-services.json` because it has API Keys.

The reason I put it in the `resources` folder is because I need to read that file in my application code as an [input stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44399422/read-file-from-resources-folder-in-spring-boot) to pass into another class.

If there is a better place to put this file please let me know.

Comment: The answer to all three of your questions is No :). The best location for this depends on where you're running your service.

Comment: @lane.maxwell I updated my question, could you re-address?

Comment: You're still missing the most crucial information: where are you running your service?

Comment: @lane.maxwell I need to use this file to access an API in a different project. But it shouldn't matter what I am doing. My question is simple, can random users on the internet look into my resources folder? Is it like the WEB-INF folder?

Comment: See my first answer to your original question.  No, they are not exposed.  No, `resources` is not the best place to put that file.  No, those files are not inaccessible... to your application, that is.

Also, it does matter where you are deploying this as to where you should house your environment-specific files :)

Comment: @lane.maxwell Why do you say "No, resources is not the best place to put that file." - if I am deploying to a container I control, how can anyone ever read that? Sure the system-admin can, but who cares, they are a part of the company

Comment: For example, if you're deploying into say, GCP Cloud Run, I would advise you to add the contents of the file into secret manager and just inject its value as a String using the `${sm://my_google_services_credentials}` (can add that to your properties or inject it directly with `@Value()`

Comment: @lane.maxwell I appreciate the suggestion, but I don't need all of that for my small application. I just need to place the .json file somewhere safe and use it in my application code. Usually, I would use `WEB-INF` but I am having trouble reading from there, so I put it in `resources`. However, I can't find a lot of info on the `resources` folder and if there are any security issues to be aware of, so I asked on SO.

Comment: Yeah, for a simple service deployed on one node, it's certainly okay to add it there; it will work just fine and will not be exposed (just make sure you haven't configured any static resource resolvers that may do that for you).  If you reach the point where you have multiple environments, you'll start to understand the pains of this approach.  Or, if that file ever changes, it takes a new build and deployment to update it.  There are lots of reasons; those are a couple.  That said, I bundle mine for POCs and externalize them for production deployments.

Comment: Since you tagged with Firebase: note that most of the values in the `google-services.json` that is used in Android apps are non-secret configuration values. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Comment: @lane.maxwell Yeah my application is small so it is not complex. Thanks.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen This is for the firebase admin SDK that you use server-side. Wouldn't those be more sensitive than the .json used in clients like android?

Comment: As far as I know the values in `google-services.json` are always meant to be used in an Android app to access Google services, so are inherently public. The (definitely more secret) values for server-side configuration would be in an account credentials file that you name yourself.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen You are correct. The server-side config file is named by yourself. Yes, I think those values are supposed to be secret.