# Displaying icon on menu bar in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, icons, embedded-resource

I have an application with a Swing GUI and I would like to add a search-field with a search-button (lupe icon) to the menu bar. However, the lupe icon won't display. Here is my code:

```
public class Ui_Frame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Ui_Frame::createAndShowGUI);
    }
    

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
         f = new JFrame("Myframe"); 

         ...

         JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
         Icon lupeIcon = new ImageIcon("Resources/lupe_icon.png");
         JButton j_searchButton = new JButton(lupeIcon);
         menubar.add(j_searchButton);

         ...

         f.setJMenuBar(menubar);
         f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
         f.pack();
         f.setVisible(true);
```

My project structure is like

```
Project 
       Src
          Ui_Frame.java
          Resources 
                 lupe_icon.png
```

The resulting button shows no icon at all :

[image]

I do not get any error message, it compiles without problems. Even when I try to catch any exception from the new ImageIcon(...) I'm not getting any hint at what the error is.

Any ideas as to what Im doing wrong here?

**EDIT**:

Here is a minimal example:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class test {

    private static JFrame f;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(test::createAndShowGUI);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        f = new JFrame("Test");
        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();

        Icon lupeIcon = new ImageIcon(test.class.getResource("/Resources/lupe_icon.png"));
        JButton j_searchButton = new JButton(lupeIcon);
        menubar.add(j_searchButton);

        f.setJMenuBar(menubar);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.pack();
        f.setSize(500,500);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

As you can see I am now loading the image with class.getResource(...) as was suggested by @AndrewThompson and @SergiyMedvynskyy, but that does not solve the problem. Also I was told that my classes should not be static, but since my Main needs to be static for me to be able to run the program and I have been told that I should start the UI with             `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(test::createAndShowGUI);`
which also forces createAndShowGUI() to be static, I do not know how to make it not static.

Comment: Seems like it could be an issue loading the resource. Can you check if `lupeIcon` is null?

Comment: @maloomeister I checked, it is not null.

Comment: Probably you should load your Icon via `new ImageIcon(Ui_Frame.class.getResource("Resources/lupe_icon.png"));`

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy Okay I tried that, did not solve problem :( . Do I maybe need to format my lupe_icon.png in any special way? At the moment its just some png I downloaded

Comment: 1) Application resources will become embedded resources by the time of deployment, so it is wise to start accessing them as if they were, right now.  An [tag:embedded-resource] must be accessed by URL rather than file.  See the [info. page for embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for how to form the URL. 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). ..

Comment: .. E.G. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/418556) hot links to an image embedded in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861852/418556). 4) `private static void createAndShowGUI()..` I've never had success loading resources in a static method. Doing it successfully requires access to the application, or context, class loader, and that is easiest done by starting from an instance of a custom class (e.g. the main app).

Comment: @AndrewThompson Alright, I have added a minimal example.

Comment: OK ..first check the resource is included in the Jar the IDE is making. If you run Windows it's easy. (Make a copy of and) rename the Jar to a .zip, then double click to open & explore. Is the image included? Is it located on the expected path?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, I posted an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After switching to `Icon lupeIcon = new ImageIcon(test.class.getResource("Resources/lupe_icon.png"));` to load the icon instead of `new ImageIcon("Resources/lupe_icon.png");` I noticed that I was getting nullpointer-exceptions, despite the image clearly being there. After some googling I found out that the resource folder apparently is not just any folder but has to be marked as the resource root folder, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328040/intellij-idea-getclass-getresource-return-null).

After marking the folder everything works fine :)

Answer (score 3):

For me it's working without mention folder "Resources" in the path,
like that:

```
Icon lupeIcon = new ImageIcon(test.class.getResource("/lupe_icon.png"));
```

But, i'm not sure your project structure is correct.

If still doesn't work, try rename folder with small 'r', and maybe also change project structure, this is my structure:

> \src\main\java... (all java files)
>
> \src\main\resources (resources folder, it displayed for me like a package)

Note - i think best is to check why u can't get the image in debug

Comment: You can also look at this lib - https://github.com/oleg-cherednik/IconManager. I have created it years ago just for this case.