# Java: How to get the path of an empty resource folder

Tags: java

My application downloads some plain CSV files from a remote server, and I want to store them into `resource/files` path.
The files folder is initially empty, and when I try to select the folder with the getResource method of the classLoader, I always get null as the return value.

```
URL localUrl = MyClass.class.getCassLoader().getResource("files"); // = null
```

But once a file is present in the files folder the above code gives me the location of the folder.

Is there a way in Java to select an empty folder within the resource folder? I am using Java 11.

Comment: I guess your build process is removing the empty directory. It's irrelevant anyway because you can't write to that directory.

Comment: You cannot use the classloader to *store* files. It should be treated as read-only. Use some other way to determine a location on the filesystem where you can cache stuff.

Comment: Have you tried `/files/` ?

Comment: Try this, hopefully it should solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50387930/5543072