# Java getResource is in wrong path

Tags: java, getresource

I hope someone can help me here, becouse I'm fighting with a problem for some time. In my main class I use this command:

```
System.out.println(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("org"));
```

The problem I've got is that it returns:

```
file:/E:/Tmp/ExamplePr/PROJEKT/proj/build/classes/java/main/org
```

instead of:

```
file:/E:/Tmp/ExamplePr/PROJEKT/proj/build/resources/java/main/org
```

The problem is that it goes into classes directory instead of resources dir. As a result I can't have access to my .fxml files I need. I'm using gradle for build and currently working with JavaFX. I've tried something like:

```
System.out.println(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/resources/java/main/org"));
```

But I just got null :(

Do you know any method to force him to use absolute path or to look for resources in resource filder or even use something like to use "../" from linux to go up. I dodn;t find any of this

Comment: You can't list the content of packages with resources anyway. getResource() should be used with the path of a resource, i.e. a file, not a directory.

Comment: Your `resources` directory is essentially a source tree.  Programs do not have access to their source files at runtime.  You are supposed to copy resources to the same place where compiled class files reside.

Comment: The issue for IntelliJ users is at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119280

Answer (score 1):

The root of your resources tree is defined by the classloader (as described in the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-)). You can define the root by explicitely setting it in your classpath or preferably by using a build tool like maven and following the conventions set and used by the tool. For maven projects the root would usually be at main/java/resources.

Answer (score 1):

`getResource` will always return the first match in the class path. So if you specify `E:/Tmp/ExamplePr/PROJEKT/proj/build/resources/java/main` before `E:/Tmp/ExamplePr/PROJEKT/proj/build/classes/java/main` in your classpath, you will get what you want.

That said, the resources are usually meant to be copied with the classes, and sometimes both are packed in a jar file, so you shouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Gradle does it right, but not IntelliJ. Do you have any hint how to do that in IntelliJ?

Answer (score -1):

With JavaFX use FXMLLoader;

```
     FXMLLoader.load(new URL(getClass().getResource("/fxml/myfxml.fxml").toExternalForm()));
```

Make sure to pass the platform appropriate separator and use a relative path.

Comment: This is mostly true (except that you *always* use a forward-slash in an argument to getResource, because the argument is a relative URL, not a file path), but it does not answer the question.

Comment: In what way does not not answer the question this will load the FXML from the resources directory.

Comment: The question is asking why the `getResource` method does not find the resource files located in the project’s `resources` directory.