# InputStream getResource() return NULL

Tags: kotlin, input, resources, inputstream

I need to get inputStream from ./resources but I got all the time NULL. Let me show you, what I did.

This is my simple code:

```
private const val CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json"
val inputStream = javaClass.getResource(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH)
```

When I set debugger on inputStream, I got null all the time.

[image: debugger]

I tried write input in different way, but it also do not work.

```
val inputStream = this::class.java.classLoader.getResource(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH)
val inputStream = javaClass.classLoader.getResource(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH)
```

So I did something like that:

```
val inputStream = javaClass.getResource(".")
```

and I think there is problem, because this path refer to `./out/test/classes` not to `./out/test/resources`
[image: debuger2]

Can I ask for some advice so that I can point to the file from ./resources?

Comment: Could you try the following? `javaClass.classLoader.getResource("credentials.json")`, i.e. using the classLoader and a ~ relative path.

Comment: I tried it, but it doesn't work that way either

Comment: Are you using Gradle, Maven, or something like that? You may want to check what Intellij has set as classpath. Maybe also helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10723585/6202869 or the comments of the answer...

Comment: I added **.json** to resources patterns in settings of IDE, but still do not work

Comment: Maven, Gradle, other? Java version?

Comment: If you're using the IDE to debug your application make sure you mark the resources directory https://imgur.com/a/vtGoFiR

Comment: I using JDK 12 and Gradle in this project. I had set resources directory.