# Eclipse: Working with Systemresources

Tags: java, eclipse, configuration, resources

Based on feedback from [URL to load resources from the classpath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java) i have changed my project, to include my image resources into Images.jar

**My project setup** is now

```
/program.jar
/Images.jar
```

In my code i load my images using

```
InputStream connectedImage = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("images/logo.png");
```

My Eclipse setup is

```
/src/...
/images/logo.png
```

**My problem**

Eclipse cannot find the Systemresource based on that url.
In order to get it to work, i have to

1. Manually create Images.jar containing my image folder
2. Add the Images.jar file to the Eclipse project

**What I need**

1. How can i configure Eclipse so i can
   use the same code to load the image
   from either Images.Jar (if run from
   commandprompt) or from the images
   folder(if run from Eclipse)?
2. Is there any way to make Eclipse
   include my /images/ folder when
   creating a runnable jar file of my
   program? Currently it does not
   include anything besides refereced
   jar files and source code.

Comment: Can you tell me how is the structure of your Images.jar? My guess is something like "images/logo.png". Is that correct?

Comment: That is correct.
The Images.jar is just a jar file of my Images folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I usually do:

1. set the directory as source folder: right click -> Build Path -> Use as Source Folder
2. change the structure of Images.jar so that the image files are on root (not under any directory)
3. change the code to:

   ```
   InputStream connectedImage = 
       ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("logo.png");
   ```

**UPDATE**: with 1, you can export the images on the same jar as the classes