# Java - Registering custom URL protocol handlers

Tags: java

I tried to register a custom URL handler for a classpath protocol, as described in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java). Here is the code:

```
package com.mycompany;

import org.junit.Test;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import com.mycompany.protocol.classpath.Handler;

public class ParserTest {
    @Test
    public void testParsing() throws MalformedURLException {      
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.protocol.handler.pkgs"));

        //URL url = new URL(null, "classpath://com.mycompany/hello-world.xml", new Handler(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()));
        URL url = new URL("classpath://com.mycompany/hello-world.xml");
    }
}
```

The test case has the following JVM arguments:

```
-Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=com.mycompany.protocol
```

The `System.out.println` line properly outputs `com.mycompany.protocol`, so the property is being set. However, it looks like it's not being taken into effect, because the above call will throw a `java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: classpath` exception.

If I provide the handler explicitly as in the commented line, everything is fine. However, I would rather not provide it explicitly - it should be done automatically.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you pass the handler to the URL's constructor? (This is just a debugging proposal, not the final solution).

Comment: Yes, if I comment out the first statement and use that one instead, it works.

Comment: Ah, sorry, did not read the question fully :-(.

Comment: @Dario can you please advise me on how to write a custom jdbc driver? If there is a good reference somewhere, please help me with its link

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have found the issue. The [original classpath handler class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java) that I used had a non-default constructor. Of course, because it had only a non-default constructor, the handler couldn't be instantiated. I apologize to everyone who have tried to debug this issue, I failed to see this connection.

Comment: don't be sorry, they will also know how to solve this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

Probably easiest way to debug such problems is to enumerate the protocol handlers registered.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The link seems no longer valid (as of 11/03/2014)