# Including an entity in an myBatis mapper file

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, ibatis, mybatis, xml-entities

I'm upgrading from iBatis 2.x to myBatis 3.0.6 and I have a mapper file which includes an external entity as follows:

```
    <!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd"
[
    <!ENTITY rating_analysis_state_cases SYSTEM "classpath://ibatis/includes/rating_analysis_state_cases.sql">
]>
```

Under iBatis this used to work fine.

The only structural change I've made is that I changed the ibatis folder to mybatis.

However when I now run it I get the following exception/stacktrace:

```
Caused By: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: classpath
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:574)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:464)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:413)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:650)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1315)
```

Has anyone got any idea as to whether something's changed that I might not know about?

Is classpath then not a known protocol? If not, what protocol could I use and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably has nothing to do with MyBATIS. Or Xerces, for that matter, since classpath protocol should be handled outside of both components, using the separation of concern principle. I doubt iBATIS had "classpath:" protocol handler registered - in the source code I have, there is no `URLStreamHandler` implementation. Maybe some other component on your stack did it though, and you removed it when switching to myBatis.

Essentially, [url to load resources from the classpath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java) has an answer for you.

All you need to do is to add a small class extending `URLStreamHandler` and implement a `URLStreamHandlerFactory`. Both are very simple and require around a dozen lines of code.

You can try looking in your previous technology stack, if there was a `java.net.URLStreamHandler` implementation done by some component (full text searching in binary files will do the trick, but then you need to see if it actually was implementing "classpath:" - the answer above provides exhaustive insight)