# load URL Resources from the Classpath on JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, url, classloader, jboss7.x

[URL to load resources from the classpath in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java) describes how to use a `URLStreamHandler` for enabling url-paths like `new URL("classpath:org/my/package/resource.extension")`

I would like to use the same Approach on JBoss AS 7, but calling `java.net.URL.setURLStreamHandlerFactory(URL.java:1102)` results in  `java.lang.Error: factory already defined`

So AS 7 has its `URLStreamHandlerFactory` allready set and this can be done only once.

Are there alternative ways to register a `URLStreamHandler` for the prefix `classpath:` on jboss or may I even get around with the `vfs`?

Answer (score 0):

Very old thread, but I got some useful answer.
As related by "David Lloyd" in JBoss issues:

> In AS7, this is just a question of calling org.jboss.modules.Module#registerURLStreamHandlerFactoryModule() with the name of the module containing the handler factory for your protocol, and ensuring that that module has a META-INF/services/java.net.URLStreamHandler file in it. Alternatively, you can specify the module name in the jboss.protocol.handler.modules system property, which works similarly to java.protocol.handler.pkgs except rather than accepting a list of package names from the application class path, it accepts a list of module names from the boot module loader.

Full details are here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-1562

Well, in my case, I just change my implementation to use Spring's  PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver:

```
ResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
  try {
    Resource [] mappingLocations = patternResolver.getResources("classpath*:" + myBaseXmlPath + "/**/*.xml");
    for(int i = 0; i < mappingLocations.length; i++) {
      // do whatever you want ...
      System.out.println(mappingLocations[i].getFile());
    }
  }
  catch(IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
```

It already deals with 'vfs' by proxing the classloader.