# Access Files in tomcat web-app from a Class in Jar inside WEB-INF/lib

Tags: java, tomcat

I have Classes that Generates jasper-reports i am using

```
private String RESOURCE_HOME = "/reports/jasper";
getClass().getResource(RESOURCE_HOME + "/srPaySlipSalaryComp.jasper").getFile();
```

I package this class in a jar and put into my application on tomcat @(WEB-INF/lib).

Now on my server i have the jaspers in [tomcat]/webapp/[myapp]/reports/jasper

How can i access these files from the Jar?

Comment: I think the reponse is in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java

Comment: I think the response is in the post 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java'

Answer (score 0):

You access a resource in web application using

```
ServletContext.getResourceAsStream(RESOURCE_HOME + "/srPaySlipSalaryComp.jasper");
```

The codes above will look from the following locations:

- web application folder
- in `/META-INF/resources` of each library present in `WEB-INF/lib`

**If you want to use the code you have**

```
private String RESOURCE_HOME = "/reports/jasper";
getClass().getResource(RESOURCE_HOME + "/srPaySlipSalaryComp.jasper").getFile();
```

the file should be present in the following two locations:

- `WEB-INF/classes`
- in any library in `WEB-INF/lib`

Comment: OK. Can i call servlet context from within a class in Jar? Because i am not using servlet? Just JSP calling the Class in my Jar.

Comment: Lets JSP pass the servlet context to that class.

Comment: No, it won't. getClass().getResourceAsStream() only looks in the classpath. It doesn't know about the webapp. And ServletContext loads from the webapp's root and from META-INF/resources, but not from the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

`getClass().getResource()` loads a resource using the class loader. So the resources it can load are resources that are accessible in the classpath. So it can only load from a jar in `WEB-INF/lib`, or from `WEB-INF/classes`, or a jar in tomcat's classpath.

One solution (probably the best one) is thus to also put the jasper files in a jar file in `WEB-INF/lib`, or in a directory under `WEB-INF/classes`.

If you really want to put the jasper files in the webapp, then you need to load the resource using [ServletContext.getResource()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).

In both solutions, what you'll get is not an URL pointing to a file, but an URL to a resource inside a jar or a war. So you shouldn't call `getFile()`. Pass the URL, or the InputStream returned by `getResourceAsStream()`, to the Jasper API.