# R: custom URL protocol handlers

Tags: r, rcurl, devtools

In R, connections supported by [url()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/connections.html) function support the scheme:

- **file://**
- **http://**
- **https://**
- **ftp://**

There is additional support in other packages:

- [RCurl](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html)
- [urltools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/urltools/index.html)
- [ssh.utils](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ssh.utils/index.html)

but i do not find anything to introduce some custom schema/protocol handler.

Something similar to Java [URLStreamHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLStreamHandler.html)

In particular, I'm looking for a way to reference data from local library packages in a "uniform" way. Something like this:

for *current* package:

- **data:///my-dataset.rda**, mapping to data folder
- **extdata:///folder1/my-datafile.txt**, mapping to [inst]/extdata/folder1

for *imported* packages:

- **data://imported-pkg/other-dataset.rda**
- **extdata://imported-pkg/folder2/other-datafile.txt**

There are several functions that enable this:

- system.file ([base](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/system.file) and [devtools](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/devtools/docs/system.file) )
- data, load/save, etc ...

but mixing network URLs and internal references in not *uniform* ...

Comment: That's what `system.file()` is for. Maybe explain why that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Java resource "classpath" urls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java/1769454#1769454

Comment: URL parsing with [urltools](https://github.com/Ironholds/urltools/blob/master/vignettes/urltools.Rmd). An interesting [article](http://www.r-bloggers.com/importing-data-into-r-from-different-sources/)