# MalformedUrlException unknown protocol classpath in Java

Tags: java

I am trying set the value of a URL instance variable as the classpath but I am getting the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: classpath
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:600)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:490)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:439)
    at com.foodprocessor.App.main(App.java:18)
C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

This is my code:

```
    public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException{
        MyEnvironmentA env = new MyEnvironmentA(new URL("classpath:"+System.getProperty("java.class.path")));
        env.run("ChocolateMilk");
     }
   }
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You already got the answer from the exception message:

> unknown protocol: classpath

Try to use `file://` protocol or `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource()` to load resource directory. Otherwise you need to implement and register `URL handler` for your `protocol` if you have to do it this way.

Please refer to [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java) for more info.

Comment: I would like to note, Spring 3.X - classpath is working fine as a "protocol"  at least when running as a Spring application, when launched locally however it is returning  `unknown protocol: classpath` so I wouldn't beat up on the OP too much!

Answer (score 0):

When you receive a `java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: classpath` double check that the file you're referring to is correct and the file exists.

`classpath:wsdl/doesNotExist` will cause unknown protocol: classpath error
Whereas:
`classpath:wsdl/foo` works just fine (assuming src/main/resources/wsdl/foo exists for example)