# Cannot put a variable URL for an Image

Tags: java, image, loops, javafx

So here's my problem: I need to instantiate Images inside a loop, but the URL doesn't work, it keeps throwing the 'url not found' error...

That's my code :

```
for (int k=0; k<=10; k++){
    String nb=String.valueOf(k);
    nombres[k]= new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("resource/"+nb+".png"));
    boutons[k]= new Button();
    boutons[k].setGraphic(new ImageView(nombres[k]));
}
```

I'm waiting for your advice?

Comment: this might enlighten you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java look through different answer, it covers getResourceAsStream

Comment: Post your project structure: this is going to expect a subpackage called `resource` in the package containing the class with the code you posted.

Comment: Also, you really don't need a stream here: use `getResource()` not `getResourceAsStream()`. You still need to ensure the path is correct, though.

Comment: When I write "resource/1.png" it works perfectly fine. I tried a print on nb to see if there was any error and there wasn't anything wrong.

Comment: So does it work for all the values if you hard-code it? Which value of `k` actually causes the exception?