# Static images not display with flying saucer and thymeleaf for generated pdf files

Tags: java, image, static, thymeleaf, flying-saucer

I am using thymeleaf as my template engin to map XHTML to HTML and flying saucer to generate a pdf file afterwards.

Now i failed to display my static images located at /src/main/resources/ inside y generated pdf file. The file itsself will be displayed fine only images disapear.

Even other locations like /src/main/resources/static or /src/main/resources/public didnt help.

My HTML / XHTML looks like:

```
<img src="images/logo_black.png"></img>
        <img src="/images/logo_black.png"></img>
        <img alt="mastercard" th:src="@{classpath:static/images/logo_black.png}" />

        <div data-src="images/logo_black.png"></div>
        <div data-src="/images/logo_black.png"></div>
        <div data-src="@{classpath:static/images/logo_black.png}"></div>
```

none of them is working properly.

The Images itself are visible by localhost:8048/logo_black.png

I dont want to refer my images with a full url (http://...)

Answer (score 1):

You can include resources from any URL (from the Internet or from your file system). Either way, there are several steps involved:

When generating the HTML from the Thymeleaf template, you can use

- `@{/some/url}` to resolve a path relative to your Web context (assuming you have a Web context), or
- `@{classpath:/some/url}` with will just leave the URL as `classpath:/some/url`, or
- simply a string value constant or a value from a variable (`${var}`), doesn't matter if it's an absolute URL `https://some/url` or relative, Thymleaf will leave them unchanged in the resulting HTML.

Before you pass the HTML to Flying Saucer, make sure the URLs are correct. Then Flying Saucer will process all URLs with a `UserAgentCallback`, by default `ITextUserAgent`.

The relevant methods in `UserAgentCallBack` are `resolveURI` and `setBaseURL`.

There is some weird logic going on in the default `resolveURI` method of `ITextUserAgent` (inherited  from `NaiveUserAgent`). If the `baseURL` is null, it will try to set it, so it's best to always set it yourself. I had better results with overriding the `resolveURI`, the following is enough to keep absolute URLs and resolve relative URLs relative to the `baseURL`:

```
@Override
public String resolveURI(String uri) {
   if (URI(uri).isAbsolute())
       return uri;
   else
       return Paths.get(getBaseURL(), uri).toUri().toString();
}
```

Finally, in order to resolve the `classpath:` protocol, [you need to define an `URLStreamHandler`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/861500/url-to-load-resources-from-the-classpath-in-java) unless there is already one defined (for example, the embedded Tomcat of Spring Boot already does supports this).

Answer (score 0):

You can render image with the help of base 64 .You just convert your image on base 64 and it will show on your web page as well as mobile view.The tags are:

```html
<img th:src="@{data:image/png ;base64,your base 64}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to specify the complete file path instead of using the relative path "images/logo_black.png" within the Thymeleaf image source attribute. To achieve this, you can create a directory named "templates" within the "resources" folder of your project. Inside this "templates" directory, you can place your images under a subdirectory named "images." For instance, you can structure it like this: "templates/images/image.png."

With this setup, you can then reference the image using the full path in the Thymeleaf th:src attribute like so:

```
<img th:src="@{classpath:/templates/images/image.png}" alt="image"/>
```

This approach ensures that you provide the complete path to the image located within your project's resources, enhancing the clarity and precision of the image reference.